# How do I launch a VM to a Specific XServer?

Tags: linux-mint, kvm, qemu, x-server, virt-manager

I have been playing around with KVM QEMU on my Linux Mint KDE machine for a while. However, I have heard it is possible to run VMs in separate XServers, and I thought it would be cool to just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*#*</kbd> to get to my other VM. 
Is it possible? Are there any drawbacks to doing this?

I am currently using KVM QEMU with Virt-Manager. I haven't really done much to run VMs from the terminal.

Comment: It's not that the VM is run on a separate X server, it's that the VM is attached to a discrete VT.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to another tty `n` with Ctrl+Alt+F`n` and run

```
xinit /usr/bin/yourcommand -- :2
```

Replace `:1` with a free display number. `:0` is mostly the number of your first X server.

Be aware that `/usr/bin/yourcommand` must contain the full path to your QEMU command; otherwise you will have an annoying xterm window on your display.

Depending on your system you may also need to specify the vt number; If you are on tty2, the command is:

```
    xinit /usr/bin/yourcommand -- :2 vt2
```

Be aware that only one (the visible) X server at a time is active. The other one is 'frozen' until you switch back to it.